# Jquery: How to select a specific previous id dynamically?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to add a comment box like you could open in Facebook when you click on "comment". So I want to select the most previous id containing "users_log_id" of the current "comment" link I'm clicking on.

Note: After "users_log_id" is always the id of the current id like this: `users_log_id38`

I tried it this way, but this doesn't seem to find the selector I'm searching for:

```
$('.comment').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selector = $('[id$=users_log_id]').prev();
    console.log(selector);
});
```

So firstly I'm just trying to find the right selector id to add that comment box I mentioned.

**EDIT:**

I just tried the answer of `guest271314` and used this:

```
$('.comment').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selector = $(this).closest('[id^=users_log_id]').prev();
    console.log(selector);
    selector.append("test");
});
```

Now it works but only if the id I'm searching for is the parent of the `comment` class I clicked (as it seems). See this image link for a visualiziation of the HTML. The arrows shows where the `comment` class I'm clicking on is:
http://s27.postimg.org/52n3x0jgj/SOOO.jpg

Comment: It's probably the [$= selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) which is looking for and `id` **ending** with `users_log_id`. Change it to  `[id^=users_log_id]` which looks for an `id` **starting** with `users_log_id` and try again

Comment: I just thought of my code... there has to be a `this`, right? Because I always want the most previous id of the current position I'm clicking on "comment".

Comment: Yes, it probably should be one. I'm thinking of something like this `$(this).find('[id^=users_log_id]').prev();`

Comment: You may get more useful answers if you post your (representative) HTML, so we can see the structure that you're working with.

Comment: I just edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: After "users_log_id" is always the id of the current id like
>   this: `users_log_id38`

Try utilizing `.prevAll()` , [`Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$('.comment').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selector = $(this).prevAll('[id^=users_log_id]').filter(":first");
    console.log(selector);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but only if the id is the parent div as it seems. I made an image to visualize it. The arrows shows where the `comment` link to click on is: http://s27.postimg.org/52n3x0jgj/SOOO.jpg

Comment: @Vaia Difficult to determine exact `html` from image, can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: This would be a bit much to post. That's why I made a screenshot and edited the image. The problem is that in one case the `comment` link I click on is on the same level as the id I'm searching for. In the other case (where it works) it's the parent. So it seems I just need a similiar function like `closest` that also searches on the same level?

Comment: Would previous `id` always be first `id` beginning with `users_log_id` , even if not parent of clicked `.comment` ?

Comment: I just realized that I made some HTML mistakes that the id I'm searching for is the parent id the first place. So now it works! Still curious why it only checks for `id` at the parent element though. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Vaia See updated post. Try utilizing `.prevAll()` , `.filter()` . Edit: _"just realized that I made some HTML mistakes that the id I'm searching for is the parent in the first place. "_ Ok; why commented requesting `html` be included at OP.  if `.closest()` returns expected results , utilize `.closest()`